# Excel: how to list all cells from the range that contain two characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to list all the cells that contain two characters within the string.

I tried something like this:

`=AND(   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("A";$C$2:$C$14)); ISNUMBER(SEARCH("T";$C$2:$C$14)))`

but it does not work...

I'd expect an output like in col "p" and "q"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```
=LET(dCheck,$A$2:$A$12,
dResult;$B$2:$B$12;
lookFor, TEXTSPLIT(C1,","),
searchResult,BYROW(dCheck, LAMBDA(r,ISNUMBER(SUM(SEARCH(lookFor,r))))),
FILTER(dResult,searchResult))
```

[image]

Comment: If I'd like to return in the C column not the results from col. A but from col. B. how could I do it? It means if cell A2 contains "t" and "a" then print in C2 the value from B2.

Comment: updated the answer - but haven't checked it ...